# Inno Setup - Cyrillic String shows up as question marks

Tags: inno-setup, pascal, pascalscript

I am running this code:

```
function CmdLineParamExists(const Value: string): Boolean;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  for I := 1 to ParamCount do
  begin
    if CompareText(Copy(ParamStr(I), 1, Length(Value)), Value) = 0 then
    begin
      Result := True;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
end;

function GetAppName(Value: string): string;
begin
  if CmdLineParamExists('/COMPONENTS=prog2') then
  begin
    Result := 'Программа 2'; //<----This shows up as ????????? 2
  end
    else
  begin
    Result := '{#SetupSetting("AppName")}';
  end;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
var
  S: string;
Begin
if CurPageID = wpSelectDir then
  begin
    S := SetupMessage(msgSelectDirLabel3);
    StringChange(S, '[name]', GetAppName(''));
    WizardForm.SelectDirLabel.Caption := S;
  end;
end;
```

Now, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Every other string shows up correctly, except when I use the result of `GetAppName`. Should I convert anything to `AnsiString` at some point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are using Ansi version of Inno Setup.

In the Ansi version, the culprit is probably the [`StringChange`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_stringchange) as it does not play nicely with non-Ansi character sets. Try using [`StringChangeEx`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_stringchangeex).

---

Though you should be using Unicode version of Inno Setup anyway.

Only the most recent version of Inno Setup, 5.6, does support Unicode string literals. So make sure you have the latest version.

---

If you are stuck with an older version:

- Encode the string like

  ```pascal
  #$041F#$0440#$043E#$0433#$0440#$0430#$043C#$043C#$0430 + ' 2'
  ```
- Or, actually the most correct way is to add a new custom message to the language files (like `Russian.isl`):

  ```
  [CustomMessages]
  Program2=Программа 2
  ```

  And load it like:

  ```pascal
  CustomMessage('Program2')
  ```

Comment: OK... That's a surprise. Anyway, can I load Component description in code instead of `CustomMessage`? e.g. in this case my component name is `prog2` and the description is `Программа 2`. I wanna avoid defining it twice.

Comment: Define the description like `{cm:Program2}`

Comment: OK. So, I should appproach the problem lterally the other way around. Let's try.

Comment: Works like a charm. I'd still wish we could reference Component description in code directly. In fact, I wish we could reference EVERYTHING from other sections...

Comment: How would you translate the entries then?

Comment: What do you mean? What I meant was I would like something like this in Code: `Setup.Components.Component[n].Description`. In this specific case, my setup is in Rusiian only, so I'm not translating those descriptions anyway.